# Want to make clickable cells of rows using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Below is the code for making rows clickable

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTableData').on('click', 'tr', function() {alert('hello');});
    });
```

But i want first two cells of rows as clickable , how can i make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myTableData').on('click', 'tr td:first-child,td:nth-child(2)', function() {
        alert('hello');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zZ43K/)

Using `:lt(2)` will not work if there are more than 1 row: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zZ43K/2/)

If you do not want to use event delegation

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myTableData tr').find('td:lt(2)').click(function () {
        alert('Hello');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zZ43K/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You CAN use `lt(2)`, but this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#myTableData tr').each(function() {
    $(this).on(
      'click', 
      'td:lt(2)', 
       function() {
         alert('hello');
    });
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ozrentk/jc84D/1/